# Domain held at one registry, need to redirect to subdomain on my own hosting provider

Tags: asp.net, dns, subdomain

There are lots of questions around this general area, but I haven't seen one that exactly mirrors what I'd like to know.  It's per the title really.  My understanding (and what I'm told by my host) is the easiest thing is just to get the transfer key and bring the DNS across to my own hosting provider.  Also I'm told by my host this doesn't affect the client's ownership of the domain itself.

Basically, I have a subdomain setup with the site (this has the same IP address as the top level domain).  So presumably just giving the other registrar that IP address will only refer it only to the TLD rather than the subdomain.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?  It's an asp.net site, I don't have a hosted directory on the client's account where I can code a redirect.

Thanks all

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then your solution might just be a 301 redirect (SEO friendly) in the .htaccess file.

[Link](http://www.dannytalk.com/redirecting-in-plesk/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the functionality allowed by your hosting provider, but I'd imagine that Host Headers might be your solution.

You'd get your domain (at the registry to point) to your hosting provider, and setup a host header(for your subdomain.domain.com address) and the site you want it to go to on your hosting provider could point to serve it.

I'm pretty sure this is how IIS works with host headers.

[Link detailing how...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008)

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for that.  Unfortunately I don't have direct IIS config access, I have to use Plesk which isn't my favourite (though better than some others I've used!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  In the end the client set their own hosting up, so I'm not actually sure which one of these to mark as the answer!  I'll be noting both of them for future cases.  If anyone would like to propose which is the most suitable, I'll confirm it.  :)